# Obtain XML element's value from REST server response using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, rest

n00b REST question. I'm making a GET request to an API's endpoint and getting the proper XML response. The question I have is, how do I get the value of a particular XML element in the servers REST response using Ruby?

So let's say one of the elements is 'Body' and I want to assign its value 'Blah blah blah' to a variable

Part of the XML response:

```
<Body>Blah blah blah</Body>
```

How would I do that with the response? Basically I want to do something like this

```
variable = params["Body"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) and have it parse the response for you.

Otherwise, you'll have to parse the response itself using a library such as Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML(response)
variable = doc.at("body").text
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use an XML parser of some kind.

It sounds like you want something like [XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/), which will turn an XML document into ruby arrays and hashes. There's tons of examples of how to use it on the page that has been linked.

One thing to be aware of is that XML to native container mappings are imperfect. If you're dealing with a complex document, you'll likely want to use a more robust parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want full XML Object Mapping, [HappyMapper](https://github.com/jnunemaker/happymapper) is a decent library, although it isn't very active anymore. It can work with XML from any source, so you'll still want something like the libraries mentioned by @Fitzsimmons or @MarkThomas to do the HTTP request.